# How To Do A Picture and Video Overlay for Instagram?

Tags: android, image, video, instagram

I've seen where some people put pictures and videos into one Instagram frame. Like, there will be a picture on the bottom and a video on the top or the square is in 4 smaller squares and 2 of them have video while the other 2 are pictures.

I got an idea that this would work perfect for, but I'm not sure how to do it. I'm using an Android for Instagram use. Is there a software or an app I can do this effect with?

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded an app called PicPlayPost. It does exactly what you are asking about and it has been popularized by Starbucks and Freeway only it's for IOS.

Vidstitch: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vidstitch from the looks of it is a good alternative.